# Is there a public NOTAM archive that's searchable by airport?

Tags: usa, datasets, notam

[Pilotweb](https://pilotweb.nas.faa.gov/PilotWeb/) lists NOTAMs currently in effect. Is it possible to view or sort the history for a particular airport?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Pilotweb, there's a "Federal NOTAM System (FNS)" section on the right side of the screen. If you select "NOTAM Search" it takes you to [another NOTAM search tool](https://notams.aim.faa.gov/notamSearch/nsapp.html#/). If you then select "Archive" from the drop-down list, you can search by date and location.

Comment: Thank you, I clicked the arrow and it turned green on my iPad. Hope that credits a correct answer.